# How to select multi items from a single Altair dropdown menu?

Tags: python-3.x, drop-down-menu, altair, python-interactive

I want to select multiple items from a dropdown menu that I created as below:

```
clients_dropdown=alt.binding_select(options=clients, name=‘Exclude Client(s)’)
clients_selector=alt.selection_single(fields=[‘Client_Name’], bind=clients-dropdown)
```

Clearly, alt.selection_single is not working, any other solution other than alt.selection_multi which is depreciated.

I also tried alt.selection_point, it did not work either.